# create a questioner and answer database?

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, automated-tests

I'm trying to implement a web application that will manage tests on various subjects. to make it easier to understand : take university subjects for example. there are 20 to 30 different subjects like math, physics, history and so on. now math-1 has 10 chapter. each chapter will have 200 to 300 questions and that means it will have 800 to 1200 multiple choices for answer(this is only chapter 1 of math-1). to design database like that, should i use XML or MSSQL? which is faster (speed is is my first concern)? which is easier to implement? and i know mssql is more secure but which one is the proper one to do it with?

thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about these two technologies. **1.** SQL Server is a relational database management system (RDBMS), XML is a markup language. You are therefore asking for a comparison between apples and oranges. **2.** The speed of XML is a meaningless concept because XML is not a dynamic system whose processing speed you could measure. **3.** It's not these technologies you are going to implement, but your solution that makes some use of one of them. **4.** XML per se isn't secure or insecure; it all depends on how your program handles its XML documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have a hosted backend with a [LAMP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)). In my experience this is not too difficult to set up with some technical knowledge and research. It is simply a backend with MySQL database and php  running on an Apache HTTP server.

You can integrate your php API into an application of sorts and have connectivity to database.
[How to install guide](http://lamphowto.com/)

Comment: im using asp.net and c# actually

Comment: Well you can keep the same principle with a .NET server with minimal ease. Just use MSSQL, because XML is not robust enough for hundreds of answers and frequent calling.